# C: CHAR_BIT do not change the char size

Tags: c, char, include, undefined

I recently founded **CHAR_BIT** and I tried to change it to 9 (or anything above 8)

```
#include <limits.h>

#define CHAR_BIT 9
```

Indeed when I **print CHAR_BIT, it returns 9** (that's correct).

But when I want to use a char, thinking it will have a higher range, it does not. **Somehow it is still with 8 bits**.

Am I doing something wrong? Or it's just not possible to change the number of bits of a char? (I don't think so, but idk)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define CHAR_BIT 9

int main()
{
    unsigned char B = 260;
    printf("%d\n",B); //returns 4 (260-4->254, 8 bit char)
}
```

Comment: That's the same as if you see a sign that says "Rome 100km" and you change it to 50km. That doesn't get you any closer to Rome.

Comment: BTW: Don't you get some message from your compiler for redefining it?

Comment: your bank balance shown on the screen is $100. Will it change if you draw additional two zeroes on the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of bits in a byte is a property of the underlying hardware, and therefore cannot be changed.

The `CHAR_BIT` macro just gives you a way to programmatically know what that value is.

Answer (score 5):

Attempting to redefine `CHAR_BIT` is undefined behavior per [**7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**, paragraph 2 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3p2):

> If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by [7.1.4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4)), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

Note that [7.1.4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4) does not apply to the `CHAR_BIT` macro, as it refers to function-like macros:

> ... Any macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing the name of the function in parentheses, because the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates expansion of a macro function name. For the same syntactic reason, it is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also defined as a macro. The use of `#undef` to remove any macro definition will also ensure that an actual function is referred to. ...

See also this note under [**J.2 Undefined behavior**, paragraph 1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2p1):

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> ...
>
> - The name of a predefined macro, or the identifier defined, is the subject of a #define or #undef preprocessing directive ([6.10.8](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8))

Answer (score 3):

`CHAR_BIT` is for the C implementation to give your program information about the number of bits in a character (equivalent to a byte, as the C standard uses the terms). It is not for your program to set the number of bits in a byte.

`CHAR_BIT` is defined by the header `<limits.h>`. If you change it, the behavior is formally undefined by the C standard, but it will not, in any ordinary compiler, change how the compiler manages bytes and object representations. It may mess up how other things defined by headers work, if they use `CHAR_BIT`. (They will be using a value for `CHAR_BIT` that does not correctly describe how the C implementation works, so whatever calculations they do with it may be incorrect and result in effects such as incorrect placement of data and incorrect calculation of size requirements.)